When will $NCLAUS be listed? We have been asking for days

Gek171gaB6oC7DqSYF5jvEMv16EQgG3JgREju5p9pump
Is the name of the coin, we have been waiting for 3 days and it hasn’t been listed, while other coins are on the platform with the same word.
